# Web encryption aes/cbc/pkcs5padding function with its own naming

Tags: javascript, angular, cryptography, steganography, cbc-mode

I have to call an encryption / decryption function so that you cannot see that it is one. For example instead of 'encryption(text)' >> 'hello(text)', or instead of 'CBC' >> 'TEST' (so more of obfuscation instead of encryption itself). Now there are various libraries that provides such functions (such as WebCrypto), but whose naming (function and parameter names) are fixed.

My question is: Whats the best way to do so?

> Should I search for an open source library and then change the names?
>
> Write my own function (
>   aes / cbc / pkcs5padding)?
>
> Or is there a more elegant way that I don't know yet?

I have to implement this in Angular.

Comment: This sounds more like obfuscation than steganography.

Comment: I'd implement a stream cipher that is fast in software instead of using AES. Calls to underlying AES functions will otherwise be immediately recognizable.